# Performance Monitor: User defined Data Collector Sets Path

Tags: c#, powershell, performancecounter

As picture below, when I am checking"Properties" for any user defined Data Collector sets (Performance Monitor), I can see a "Directory" tab which refers the Path for it.

[image]

Is there any C# code or powershell script or any other way to get the same path by just providing user defined Data Collector sets name?  Thanks!

Comment: Is PLA.dll assembly in "%windir%\System32\PLA.dll" will be useful?

Answer (score 0):

Below is the Powershell code you can use just change the path in the code and data collectors as per your need it will automatically start the performance data collector with given process name in the code

first if code is just to bypass the script execution policy in the powershell for any host machine and run the script with the admin rights you can remove that if script execution is enabled

```
    if (!([Security.Principal.WindowsPrincipal][Security.Principal.WindowsIdentity]::GetCurrent()).IsInRole([Security.Principal.WindowsBuiltInRole] "Administrator")) { Start-Process powershell.exe "-NoProfile -ExecutionPolicy Bypass -File `"$PSCommandPath`"" -Verb RunAs;}

Param(
  [string]$name = "Test"
)

$datacollectorset = New-Object -COM Pla.DataCollectorSet
$datacollectorset.DisplayName = $name;
$datacollectorset.Duration = 14400 ;
$datacollectorset.SubdirectoryFormat = 1 ;
$datacollectorset.SubdirectoryFormatPattern = "yyyy\-MM";
$datacollectorset.RootPath = "%systemdrive%\PerfLogs\Admin\" + $name ;

$DataCollector = $datacollectorset.DataCollectors.CreateDataCollector(0) 
$DataCollector.FileName = $name + "_";
$DataCollector.FileNameFormat = 0x1 ;
$DataCollector.FileNameFormatPattern = "yyyy\-MM\-dd";
$DataCollector.SampleInterval = 10

$counters = @(
        "\Memory\Available MBytes",
        "\Memory\Page Faults/sec",
        "\Memory\Page Reads/sec",
        "\Memory\Page Writes/sec",
        "\Memory\Pages Input/sec",
        "\Memory\Pages Output/sec",
        "\Process(CloudHASHService)\*",
        "\Processor(_Total)\% Idle Time",
        "\Processor(_Total)\% Interrupt Time",
        "\Processor(_Total)\% Privileged Time",
        "\Processor(_Total)\% Processor Time",
        "\Processor(_Total)\% User Time"
) ;

$DataCollector.PerformanceCounters = $counters

try
{    
    $datacollectorset.DataCollectors.Add($DataCollector) 
    $datacollectorset.Commit("$name" , $null , 0x0003) | Out-Null
    $datacollectorset.Start($false);
}
catch [Exception] 
{ 
    Write-Host "Exception Caught: " $_.Exception -ForegroundColor Red 
    return 
}
```